# Django - Is it possible to show image on page without make it static?

Tags: python, django

I'm building a web page to modify images(cropping, scaling, etc..) based on the meta data which is the output of my python scripts. In each meta data specify the index of the particular image in the field (ex: meta data: [idx: 01, ..,..] then image01 will be operated.) However in my case, there are tons of image source(dataset_01, dataset_02, ...) and in each image dataset it contains 10000 images. Now my solution is to put the image dataset into the static folder and command

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

However it took tons of time as django has to collect all the 10000 image source everytime I add a new image dataset. I'm just wondering is there any possible that I don't have to collect those images as static file and just directly open the image files in the folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way can be solution:

in `settings.py`:

`STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_root')`

then locate your static files on 'static_root' folder.

then if django is running with `DEBUG=False`, it will serve static files on that folder with `STATIC_URL`.

> note: if you want to serve static file with django `runserver`, you have to add `--insecure`, so like this: `runserver --insecure`

Comment: it still needs me to run collectstatic statement if i want to use the image

Comment: It's weird -- because collectstatic means just move static files in `STATIC_DIRS` to `STATIC_ROOT`.  did u add images on `STATIC_ROOT` directory?

Comment: I add the image directly to static_root but nothing show on the sites. Instead, if i put in staticfiles_dir and run collectstatic it does copy file from staticfiles_dir to my static_root then image show on the site.

Comment: However I want to skip the step and let my django can show the image when I directly put image in static_root. Because applying collectstatic takes tons of time if the images is alot.

Comment: its so weird that after I do collectstatic it copied my image from staticfiles_dir to static_root and the image can show. Then I deleted that image in the static_root, the image still show. What is the concept behind this scenario??

Comment: are u set `DEBUG=False` in settings.py?

Comment: I set debug as true

Comment: i tried both but not work as well. anything else i should check?

Comment: Is it possible to have 2 static root?

Comment: No, you can not do that. STATIC_ROOT is only one folder.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42685535/django-httpresponse-2-query-result-in-json-format

Comment: just did. can you help me with that json problem. been trying whole day...