# Django - HttpResponse 2 query result in JSON format

Tags: json, django

I have 2 query results from the database and try to return it in json format like this.

```
    gt_buffer = ev_ground_truth.objects.filter(alg=_alg, exp=_exp,nFrame=_nframe)
    dt_buffer = ev_detection.objects.filter(alg = _alg, exp=_exp, nFrame=_nframe)
    json_gt_bb = serializers.serialize('json', gt_buffer)
    json_dt_bb = serializers.serialize('json', dt_buffer)
    dict_bb_buffer = {'gt': json_gt_bb, 'dt': json_dt_bb}
    json_bb_buffer = json.dumps(dict_bb_buffer, ensure_ascii=False)

    return HttpResponse(dict_bb_buffer, content_type = "application/json")
```

And at the front-end,

```
    $.ajax({
      url: '/results/get_nframebbs',
      data: {
        'exp':_exp,
        'alg':_alg,
        'nframe':data[i]['fields'].nFrame
       },
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function (data) {
          alert(data.length)
       }
    });
```

However the alert never be called. But if I just serialize 1 query result and return the alert is called successful with a popup.

```
        gt_buffer = ev_ground_truth.objects.filter(alg=_alg, exp=_exp,nFrame=_nframe)

        json_gt_bb = serializers.serialize('json', gt_buffer)



        return HttpResponse(json_gt_bb, content_type = "application/json")
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Are you using DRF?(Django Rest Framework?)

Comment: I don't know what is that. I dont think so.

Comment: @Beomi Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy. Just return 2 query result as string and parse at the front-end.

```
    gt_buffer = ev_ground_truth.objects.filter(alg=_alg, exp=_exp,nFrame=_nframe)
    dt_buffer = ev_detection.objects.filter(alg = _alg, exp=_exp, nFrame=_nframe)
    json_gt_bb = serializers.serialize('json', gt_buffer)
    json_dt_bb = serializers.serialize('json', dt_buffer)
    dict_bb_buffer = {'gt': json_gt_bb, 'dt': json_dt_bb}


    return JsonResponse(dict_bb_buffer, status = 201)
```

and at the front-end:

dataType: 'json',

```
     success: function (data) {

                gt = JSON.parse(data.gt.substring(1,data.gt.length-1));
                dt = JSON.parse(data.dt.substring(1,data.dt.length-1));
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the response as an argument in your success function, not the json data directly. you can access to your data like this:

```
success: function (response) {
      var gt = response.responseJSON.gt;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. It never go into that success function.